# After upgrade of keycloak, angular 13 app gets redirect error on logout

Tags: angular, keycloak, logout

My Keycloak server has been upgraded to 20.0.2, so in my angular 13 app, I've installed keycloak-js 18.0.1 and keycloak-angular 10.0.2. I can't go up to keycloak-js 20 because it would require angular 15 and we're not ready to do that.

So, I've read from different sites that upgrading to keycloak-js 18 would solve my logout error, but I still get the same error. The Valid redirectURIs is set to http://localhost:4200/* in the admin console.

In the code I call:

```
this.keycloakService.logout();
```

The logout URL issued is:

```
http://localhost:8010/realms/<snip>/protocol/openid-connect/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/&id_token_hint=<token>
```

The response is:

> We are sorry...
> Invalid redirect uri

I've been reading about this all day and I'm losing hope. Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: Is this a typo http://localhost:8010/realms/<client> or do you mean http://localhost:8010/realms/<realm> ?

Comment: For testing purpose did you try to redirectURIs to just * and see if it works?

Comment: @dreamcrash, yes, it was a mistake because our client and realm are very similar, so got confused. I just tried * as redirectURI and it can't even authenticate with that. I tried giving [http://localhost:4200/*](http://localhost:4200/*) as redirectURI and it gives the same redirect error on logout.

Comment: How about redirectURI = http://* and https://* and Origins = * ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that the server admin client option Valid post logout redirect URIs needs also to be set to http://localhost:4200, then it works.